# How to name a enum with the name being different from its name in a database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enums, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a model with `enum`:

```
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  enum my_enum: [:status1, :status2, :status3, :status4]


  # .........
end
```

I want to field in the database to be titled "status", whereas in my model it should be titled "my_enum"

Is this possible? How to specify the name of the source column in database?

I'm aware of "_prefix", "postfix" properties of "enum" in Rails and this isn't what I need.